# In II7, what is the difference between an "Application", a "Module" and a "Handler"?

Tags: delphi, iis-7, isapi

Currently, my understanding is as follows.

- When a request is received by IIS, it transitions between several states (BEGIN_REQUEST, EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER, END_REQUEST, etc).
- A "Module" is a DLL (dynamic link library) that extends the functionality of IIS at one or more of those request states. For example, the "PHP Module" is a DLL that hooks into IIS at the EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER state to parse and execute PHP scripts.

The above is rather easy to digest (and is very similar to how Apache provides extensions). However, I do not have a clear understanding of "Handlers", "Handler Mappings" and "Applications".

1. What is a "Handler"? What is a "Handler Mapping"?
2. What is the difference between a "Module" and a "Handler"?
3. What is the difference between a "Module" and an "Application"?

With this last question, if I enable an ISAPI DLL built with Delphi, what is the difference between this and an application? Can my ISAPI DLL be added as an executable to IIS in two different ways, one via the regular route and one via adding an "Application"?

(Note: I do understand that "Application Pools" is used to segregate the executables producing dynamic content.)

**EDIT:** In the IIS developer guide, there is a small paragraph which helps clarify the difference between "Module" and a "Handler", quoted below.

> When planning to develop an IIS feature, the first question you should ask is whether this feature is responsible for serving requests to a specific url/extension, or applies to all/some requests based on arbitrary rules. In the former case, your should be a handler, and in the latter, a module.

Essentially, I understand that both "Handlers" and "Modules" are extensions to the functionality of IIS, but the former response to specific requests (e.g., the PHP handler responds to every request where the file name ends with ".php") while the latter provides decorator-like functionality (e.g., GZIP compressing the response body of a handler). Reference: http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework

My main question now is, **what is the difference between an IIS7 "Application" and an II7 "Handler"?**

Comment: how is this Delphi related?

Answer (score 2):

#### Handlers

A *Handler* is often used to handle requests to specific types of page extension or url. For example each of the many different extension types, `*.asp`, `*.aspx`, `*.php` and so on have their own handler types as defined in IIS 7+'s MMC Handler Mappings feature.

In old school IIS6 parlance they'd be the equivalent of Script Maps.

For more information see:

> http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers

#### Modules

Modules consist of code that plug into the request pipeline in your application for perform a specific function upon every request. For example, logging or some sort of security feature that isn't available out of the box.

For more information see:

> http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules

#### Applications

An *Application* is comprised of all of your website code (including any modules you may have written) running in your website. By default a single website will have a single Application known as the Root Application. It's also possible to create additional applications inside the same website which will have their own application and session state distinct from the others.

For more information see:

> http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application